# Skip landing page in NavHost when user opens the app for second time using Jetpack Compose with Flow

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have an app with `HorizontalPager` at startDestination screen and after I go to the last page, the app shows the home page.
When I open the app for second time it should show Home page immediately and never again show that startDestination screen with `HorizontalPager`.
I used dataStore and it works, but the problem is that every time I open the app it flashes for a second that `HorizontalPager` landing page and then it switches to the home page.
I used flow to get true/false state of the app start, so it will know it will know app was already opened for first time.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    @ExperimentalAnimationApi
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            WebSafeTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                    val navController = rememberNavController()
                    Navigation(navController)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@ExperimentalAnimationApi
@ExperimentalMaterialApi
@ExperimentalFoundationApi
@ExperimentalPagerApi
@Composable
fun Navigation(
    navController: NavHostController
    ) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val preferencesManager = PreferencesManager(context)
    val preferencesFlow = preferencesManager.preferencesFlow
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val result = remember { mutableStateOf(Constants.SKIP_LANDING_PAGE) }
    scope.launch {
        result.value = preferencesFlow.first().skipLandingPage
    }

    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
//it goes it this line 2 times, first time when the app opens and second time after the flow is finished
        startDestination = if (result.value) Screen.HomeScreen.route else Screen.LandingScreen.route,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        composable(
            route = Screen.LandingScreen.route
        ) {
            Landing(navController)
        }
        composable(
            route = Screen.SkipChooseCountryScreen.route
        ) {
            ChooseCountry()
        }
        composable(
            route = Screen.HomeScreen.route
        ) {
            Home(navController)
        }
    }
}
```

It goes to NavHost for the first time after app openes and it always returns FALSE as it is default value, after that flow returns TRUE(so it knows app was opened at least once before) and then it openes the correct screen.

I have no idea how to make NavHost to wait that flow to finishes. I tried to put NavHost into the scope but it didn't allow me.

Comment: You can collect flow to state using `collectAsState`, e.g. `val result by preferencesFlow.collectAsState(null)`.  It'll still be `null` in case when preference manager doesn't have value at first render, for such case you may need to display a splash screen of some kind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also need to read data from data store, so this is how I do it:

```
Crossfade(
    targetState = state.value.loadState
) { loadState ->
    when (loadState) {
        LoadState.NOT_LOADED -> Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize())
        LoadState.SHOW_PIN -> PinScreen(
            loadState = loadState,
            state = state,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        )
        LoadState.SHOW_CONTENT -> MainContent(
            state = state,
        )
    }
}
```

Initially my state is `NOT_LOADED` so I just display an empty box that fills the screen. You could alternatively display a spinner, or your app's logo. Once the data has been loaded, I show the PIN screen if the user has PIN enabled, or the main screen otherwise.

Also, note that you should not have your viewpager screen as your root destination, your home page should be your root destination, and you should conditionally navigate to the viewpager if the user has not seen your onboarding flow yet.  Check [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional) for details.

Comment: Your answer is OK, but I am interested if it is possible to make this loading states around NavHost or I am required to use them in starting destination composable?

Comment: You can have the NavHost inside the crossfade, if you are loading you show a spinner or something else, if you are not loading then you show the navhost.